# expression must be a modifiable lvalue on a struct array that is modifiable

Tags: c, arrays, struct

i have a program that is supposed to stimulate the compiler of a certain language, using structs i made each "word" of memory have a 15 int array of "bits", the problem is that every time i try to compile this test i get 2 errors:

expression must be a modifiable lvalue

and
expected an expression

I have no idea why the second one appears,
and when I searched the first error I found that the left value being non-modifiable even though I cant see why.

note: I tried to use a pointer instead of an array and it didn't change a thing

code:

```
word memory[1000];

    struct bit {
            unsigned int bt : 1;
        }typedef bit;

    struct word {
            bit mem[15];
        }typedef word;

        memory[0].mem = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

edit: please do not suggest changes to the structs because they are part of a big program and it will take too much work to change them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are not directly assignable in C. However, structs *containing* arrays are, so what you can do is this:

```
word w = { { {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1} } };
memory[0] = w;
```

With C99 you can use a compound literal and say:

```
memory[0] = (struct word){ { {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1}, {1} } };
```

(In C++ you could use unconstrained temporary values.)

Comment: thank you! this worked.
also i'm sorry for asking such a stupid question i'm pretty new to c